# What is the Time $t$ when a Beam of Light travels Infinite distance?

Tags: visible-light, speed-of-light, mathematics, regularization

[image: D=-1/12]

Now, by the Picture we know that $D=-1/12$ by $1+2+3+4+...=-1/12$

Therefore,
By Speed$=D/t$

3*10^8=(-1/12)/t

Therefore,

Time ‘t’=-1/(12 * 3 * 10^8)

t=-1/(36*10^8)

How is this Possible?

Please Note that I am not a Physicist/Mathematician, just a high school student.

Comment: 1+2+3+... $\ne$ -1/12

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2170792/560462

Answer (score 2):

> How is this Possible?

It isn’t. $1+2+3+4+...\ne-1/12$. Although this mathematical mistake is undeservedly famous it is nevertheless a mistake.

The Riemann zeta function $$\zeta(s=\sigma +i t) = \Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} n^{-s}$$ for $\sigma>1$. Also, $\zeta(-1)=-1/12$. But since $-1 \ngtr 1$ it is clear that $$\zeta(-1)\ne\Sigma_{n=1}^{\infty} n^1=1+2+3+4+...$$

Answer (score 0):

Well, theoretically, anything (including light) has to take infinite time like any other thing in existence to travel an infinite distance! Although, if it is ONLY light in this universe of yours, time wouldn't exist because theoretically it needs matter to be experienced! I hope the first sentence answers your question.
Also, if it's D/t then it's still infinite because it traveled an infinite distance and infinity divided by any cardinal number, is still infinity!

Answer (score 0):

It is important to specify how the travel time is to be measured.  If it's measured by an observer traveling along with the light - at the speed of light - then the observer will not experience time passing at all.  He and the light will travel to anywhere in the universe in what he measures as no time.  To an observer in any other inertial frame (that is, moving at a speed physically possible for a massive object), it would take N years for light to travel between objects N light years apart if the objects are stationary with respect to the observer.  So, it would take an infinite length of time for light to move an infinite distance, from that observer's perspective.